# Generic type not getting the passed type from args

Tags: typescript

#### The Problem:

```js
type Method = "get" | "post" | "put" | "patch" | "delete" | "head" | "options";

export interface TRoute<TMethod, TResponse = unknown, TParmas = undefined> {
  payload: {
    method: TMethod;
    url: string;
  };
}

export const route = <TResponse, TMethod extends Method = Method>(
  method: TMethod,
  url: string
): TRoute<TMethod, TResponse> => ({
  payload: { method, url },
});

const result = route<{ result: string[] }>("get", "/index")
```

### Result

Type of result is:

```js
const result: TRoute<Method, {
    result: string[];
}, undefined>
```

### Expected Result

```js
const result: TRoute<"get", {
    result: string[];
}, undefined>
```

Please note that I don't want to pass the second generic type and I want the TMethod to get its type from the method argument.

Comment: TypeScript does not have partial type inference. You can't explicitely provide a type for `TResponse` **and** have `TMethod` automatically inferred by the arguments. So when you explicitely provide `TResponse` and don't provide `TMethod` the default type is chosen.

Comment: Workarounds for partial type argument inference (as requested in [ms/TS#26242](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26242)) involve either currying (so `route<{ result: string[] }>()("get", "/index")`) or using a dummy parameter (so `route(null! as {result: string[]}, "get", "/index"})`).  See the answers to the linked questions for more information.